# Reading wordpress RSS with C# - Content different

Tags: c#, wordpress, rss

I'm trying to read a RSS generated by wordpress with full text activated. On firefox and IE9 an item data contains the element `content:encoded`:

```
<content:encoded><![CDATA[bla bla bla]]></content:encoded>
```

but when in a C# program I request the same rss url this node is not present. I do my C# request like this:

```
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
   var xml = client.DownloadString(url)
```

Does I have to add an header to the request to have this specific field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need WebClient to download rss.

```
XDocument wp = XDocument.Load("http://wordpress.org/news/feed/");
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");

foreach (var content in wp.Descendants(ns + "encoded"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(content.Value)+"\n\n");
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem is related with compression. If the client doesn't support compression, then server doesn't send contents.

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip,deflate,sdch";

var zip = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(
    web.OpenRead("http://www.whiskymag.fr/feed/?post_type=sortir"), 
    System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress);

string rss = new StreamReader(zip, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: @Gregoire, above example works. I tried it before posting. Do you use a different url?

Comment: I personally don't use XDocument.Load from the client side, because it is single threaded, and if the destination site is running slow, I could see my UI lock up.  If you're going to use this, I'd recommend not using it in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing Wordpress is choosing the "wrong" output format based on your `Accept` header. Which feed is used is decided in `/wp-content/feed.php`:

```
$types = array(
    'rss'  => 'application/rss+xml',
    'rss2' => 'application/rss+xml',
    'rss-http'  => 'text/xml',
    'atom' => 'application/atom+xml',
    'rdf'  => 'application/rdf+xml'
);
```

so instead of `text/xml`, try accepting `application/rss+xml`.

Comment: I have tried application/rss+xml (and also application/rdf+xml) but the content node is still not here! Is there another header that is taken in account ?